# zxing- QRCode decoding issue

Tags: linux, image-processing, qr-code, zxing

I installed zxing application in our Linux server.
I used that for decoding the qrcode from the scanned copy of the signature sheet which our tutors uploading through php script.
Few picture quality it can decode and few it can not.

Can anybody tell me which format or resolutions it can work 100%.

Comment: How did you install "zxinng application" ? I thought it is a library

Answer (score 0):

Nothing works 100%. All resolutions are scannable by the library, within reason. The [supported formats are](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/):

- UPC-A and UPC-E
- EAN-8 and EAN-13
- Code 39
- Code 93
- Code 128
- QR Code
- ITF
- Codabar
- RSS-14 (all variants)
- Data Matrix
- PDF 417
- Aztec

Answer (score 0):

If you have the choice, prefer lossless formats: BMP, GIF, PNG. But this no warranty that it will always work well.

Comment: Is there any limitation in file size [KB, MB etc]?

Comment: I'm not familiar with zxing but limitations should be in according to your app.

Comment: Any reasonable image quality and resolution is fine. The library uses `javax.imageio` to read images, so should read most anything. The issues is simply that some issues will not be decoded; it is not a problem of image format or resolution though.